# C# Creating buttons for WPF app that can connect and save the connection to a Serial Port

Tags: wpf, button, serial-port

Hi there I'm a newbie in programming, hope it's the right place to start!

Currently I designed a program which is suposed be UI for a control program of an old 80s robot. The problem is that I need to open a COM port (COM2) assign that function to a button and save that, so I can use it all around the menus.

Any help would be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Button Click="Button_Click">Open Serial Port</Button>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
private System.IO.Ports.SerialPort _serialPort;    
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_serialPort == null)
            _serialPort = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort("COM2");

        try
        {
            _serialPort.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // Do something
            throw;
        }
    }
```